# Neural Network always predicting the same class

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

I've developed an Image classifier using a convolutional neural network. The whole code is written using Keras. The dataset contains .jpg images with sizes 360X480 and labels 0,1,2 and 3. The data has been balanced so there is the same amount of pictures for each label both in the training and validate datasets.

I've organized my data in directories to use a data generator function that will load the images while the model is training.

The organization of the data is as follows:

```py
Data:
    Train: 0:  a1.jpg
               a2.jpg
               ...
           1:  b1.jpg
               b2.jpg
               ...
    ...
```

Same for all labels and for test data.

The code used to define and fit the neural network is the following:

```py
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(128, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', input_shape=input_shape, padding="valid"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', padding="valid"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', padding="valid"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(512, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(4, activation="softmax"))


opt = SGD(lr=learning_rate)
model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer=opt,
    metrics=["accuracy"])

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
                width_shift_range=0.05,
                height_shift_range=0.05,
                rescale=1./255,
                horizontal_flip=True)

validate_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        path_data + '/train',
        shuffle = True,
        target_size=input_generator, 
        batch_size=batch_size)

validation_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        path_data + '/validate',
        shuffle = True,
        target_size=input_generator,
        batch_size=batch_size)

steps_per_epoch = np.ceil(train_size/batch_size)
validation_steps = np.ceil(validation_size/batch_size)


H = model.fit_generator(
        train_generator,
        steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,
        epochs=epochs,
        validation_data=validation_generator,
        validation_steps=validation_steps)
```

When I run the network for training, the training accuracy stays around 0.25 and when calculating a confusion matrix on the test dataset, I realize it's predicting everything to be in the same class. What could be happening?

I've tried many different experiments to determine where could the problem come from:

- I've changed the network to a VGG architecture, training all the layers, reducing the size of the pictures to 150x150 with different learning rates (0.001, 0.01, 0.1).
- I've changed the dataset to be only 16 photos for training (4 for each label) and 5 for validation (1 for each of three labels, and 2 for the fourth label). Using VGG like in the last bullet point, with 100 epochs (trying to force overfitting) the network hasn't learned anything. I even tried to reduce the size of the pictures to be 50x50 and the problem persists.
- After this attempts, I've created a dataset of 16 pictures (150x150) for training, 5 for validating where each picture is just a plain color (red, blue, yellow, green, one for each label), no shapes, no images, only plain color. The neural network hasn't been able to learn (in the same configuration than the previous two bullet points).

None of this have solved the problem, the network still predicts everything to be from the same class.

**CURRENT STATE**

1. I transformed my data to be classified as binary (merged labels 0, 1 and 2, 3). This first step makes sense since the labels were levels of dirt in a pipe (0: 0-25%, 1: 25-50%, ...).
2. Used ResNet50 architecture without initial wheights.
3. Cropped the images to be 224x224.

Results: the output of the model for a few images makes sense (it's not [1,0]), and the accuracy rose along the epochs (at least in the training dataset, meaning that the network is learning).

Next steps will be optimizing the model, and maybe coming back to the initial label classification since it was the original purpose of the project.

Comment: Have you change the network to be deeper? It's way too small with less than 10 weighted layers. Your model here is even smaller than `LeNet` which takes 32*32 images!!

Comment: And also, NEVER use sigmoid for any layers other than output for a CNN.

Comment: Previously I tried with a VGG network, I'm adding the process I followed in the question.

Comment: Better plot the log of both `acc` and `loss`, it's really helpful.

Comment: Wait why you train only the last 5 layers?

Comment: If the other layers are just randomized weight then how could it possibly learn anything?

Comment: I used the pretrained layers from Imagenet for the other layers.

Comment: Nonono, if you want to freeze then just freeze the whole bunch of them and train only what you just added, then unfreeze and train them all together after the `loss` getting smaller.

Comment: And if your images aren't anything near what in imagenet then just train them all, don't freeze anything

Comment: I tried what you suggested and some other ideas I had and it didn't solve the problem. I'm explaining more in detail in the question the different experiments I did.

Comment: Also is the predicted output something like `[1, 0, 0, 0]`, has 1 at the first element and the rest are 0? If this the case then it's a sign of the model is using randomized weights somewhere.

Comment: Do you have the whole project on github? I found this is really strange.

Comment: It is a private project from work, so I can't share the repository. About the output, I study the accuracy history and I see that it doesn't move much from 0,25. Also, after training the model I calculate the confusion matrix between the model predictions in the test dataset and the actual labels. In this case, all the labels predicted belong to the same class.
About the output you mention being like [1,0,0,0], what output are you referring to?

Comment: The "real" output of the network before doing something like `np.argmax()`, just `print(model.predict(imgs))`.

Comment: Normally the output should be like `[0.7, 0.1, 0.15, 0.05]`, not any class being full 1 or absolute 0.

Comment: Also did you try something like, `model = keras.applications.resnet.ResNet50(weights=None, classes=4)` without editing the model?

Comment: I got some good results, I'm adding them to the question.

Comment: If it's levels of dirt in a pipe then I think you should use `binary_crossentropy` + `sigmoid` instead of `categorical_crossentropy` + `softmax`. BCE can output like [0.5, 0.6, 0.9, 0.7] which makes sense in this case(even if it's 2 doesn't mean high score on 1 or 3 is wrong), softmax can only be like [0.01, 0.05, 0.9, 0.04], summation=1.